# Is there any way to read stream that doesn't support reading operation?

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I use a third party DLL that creates private FileStream and writes something into it.

I used reflection to access that stream and I really need to copy bytes from stream.

```
writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRecorded); //writer is the instance of class defined in DLL

FieldInfo fi_out_stream = writer.GetType().GetField("outStream", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
FileStream outStream = (FileStream)fi_out_stream.GetValue(writer);

FieldInfo fi_data_size_pos = writer.GetType().GetField("dataSizePos", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Int64 dataSizePos = (Int64)fi_data_size_pos.GetValue(writer);

if (this.CurrentWaveMS == null) //this is MemoryStream where I want to store bytes from outStream
{
    this.CurrentWaveMS = new MemoryStream();
    outStream.CopyTo(this.CurrentWaveMS); //getting read not supported exception here
}
else
{
    long curr_pos = outStream.Position;
    long diff = outStream.Length - this.CurrentWaveMS.Length;
    byte[] buff = new byte[diff];
    outStream.Position -= diff;
    outStream.Read(buff, 0, (int)diff); //and here
    outStream.Position = curr_pos;

    this.CurrentWaveMS.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
}
```

I need to duplicate `outStream`. Is there any tricks to access bytes stored in stream?

Comment: Can't you just copy the stream to another variable?

Comment: @PauloLima - this is not duplicating the stream. And what's the use of it if I can't read it. I need to create `readable` stream and use it.

Comment: [ ALERT ], do not do that.  There is a reason that their stream is not public.  Using reflection is always a bad idea not only due to its performance implications but especially since you are peaking into a third party library.  Is there not some sort of exposed API that allows you to do this the correct and intended way?

Comment: @DavidPine - I really need it and there is no other way to access bytes stored in stream. This lib creates a file and continuously adding chunks into it without closing it. I need to analyze file content exactly while it being updated.

Comment: "I need to analyze file content exactly while it being updated." Why not use `FileSystemWatcher` ?

Comment: @MikkoViitala - could I use it to get bytes from file at every modification?

Comment: Tested it and no... it's not broadcasting events while file is open.